Embedding $S^1$ into Möbius strip
An assignment problem I'm working on right now is formulated as follows:

Definition: The Möbius band is the quotient of the square $I^2 = [0,1]^2$ by the relation $(0,y) \sim (1,1-y)\forall y \in I$.


Let M be a Möbius band. Construct an embedding $f: S^1 \hookrightarrow M$ that is not a composition of an embedding $S^1 \hookrightarrow I^2$ and the quotient projection $q:I^2 \rightarrow M$.


My attempt at an answer begins by writing M as $M = \{\{(x,y)\}|y \in [0,1], x \in (0,1)\} \cup \{\{0,y),(1,1-y)\}|y\in[0,1]\}$ and defining $f:\{(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}cos(t),\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}sin(t))|t \in [0,2\pi)\} \rightarrow M$ by $(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}cos(t),\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}sin(t)) \mapsto \{(\frac{t}{2\pi},\frac{1}{2})\}$ if $t \in (0,2\pi)$ and $\{(0,\frac{1}{2}),(1,\frac{1}{2})\}$ if t = 0. So the image set is $f(S^1) = \{\{(\frac{t}{2\pi},\frac{1}{2})\}|t \in (0,2\pi)\} \cup \{\{(0,\frac{1}{2}),(1,\frac{1}{2})\}\}$. Now I'm trying to show that this function is continuous onto the image set to show that it is an embedding, where I tried the following:
Suppose V is an open set in $f(S^1)$. That means that $V = f(S^1) \cap U$, where $U\in M$ is a set such that $q^{-1}(U)$ is open in $I^2$ under the subspace topology and $q: I^2 \rightarrow M$ is the quotient projection (here I've just used the definition of quotient and subspace topology). Continuity of f is the condition that for any such V, $f^{-1}(V)$ is open in $S^1$ under its subspace topology. So taking the preimage of V, $f^{-1}(f(S^1)\cap U) = S^1 \cap f^{-1}(U)$. My issue now is that in general $f^{-1}(U)$ shouldn't be well-defined as f isn't surjective. I feel like I'm either on a completely incorrect track, have missed something obvious, or have no idea what I'm doin, so I'm basically looking for a bit of help on how to move forward. My second question is regarding the condition that f shouldn't be a composition of an embedding into the square and the quotient projection. I don't really have any intuition for what this condition is really asking, and I have absolutely no idea how to check if my function actually satisfies that condition, let alone find one that would. I'm still pretty new to topology, so apologies if some of this doesn't make any sense.

Think about the boundary of the Möbius band. Then think about formulas.

You could also think about the map induced by $i \mapsto (i, 1/2) : I \to I^2$.

Hint
Think about the map $F: I \to I^2$ defined by $F(t)= (2t,0) $ for $0 \le t < 1/2$ and $(2t-1,1)$ for $1/2 \le t \le 1$. $F$ induces an embedding $f$ from $S^1$ to $M$ with the quotient map. However $f$ is not a composition of an embedding from $S^1$ to $I^2$ and the quotient map.
Note: regarding the continuity of $f$, you should use general results about quotient maps. For the fact that it is an homeomorphism to its image, the compactness of $I$ has to be use.

I'm having a hard time seeing how F induces the embedding from $S^1$ to $M$. Also, it seems like you're using the terms quotient map and quotient projection interchangeably (I might be mistaken) whereas I was under the impression that they had distinct meanings.

In fact, if $\pi$ denotes the projection from $I^2$ onto $M$, $\pi \circ F$ is continuous. And $\pi \circ F$ induces a continuous map from $S^1$ to $M$ when you define $S^1$ as a quotient of $I$.
